# Using bcp utility from within a stored procedure to output records to a text file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bcp

I have been using the bcp utility from the command line to save the result of a query to a text file e.g.

```
C:>  bcp "SELECT Name FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Employees]" queryout "filepath.txt" -c -T
```

I am currently trying to find away to execute this and similar bcp commands from a stored procedure.

Research for solution

- Investigated xp_cmdshell stored procedure (Disabled for security reasons)
- Use SQL Server agent and use job steps to invoke the command shell
  [Post from mssqltips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/)
  .

Attempt at a solution (Code below lies within stored procedure)

```
DECLARE @job NVARCHAR(100)
SET @job ='execute_bcp' 

EXEC msdb..sp_add_job @job_name = @job, 
  @description = 'Execute bcp command', 
  @owner_login_name = 'sa',
  @delete_level = 1

EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name = @job,
  @step_id = 1,
  @step_name ='Command Shell Execution', @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC',
  @command = 'bcp "SELECT Name FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Employees]" queryout "filepath.txt" -c -T',
  @on_success_action =1

EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_name =@job

EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = @job
```

The outcome of running this stored procedure is 
'execute_bcp' has started.

However, when I check the file path location specified above **the file has not been created.**

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Comment: Does the job finish? Does the job log show any errors? Are you checking the path on your SQL Server?

Comment: try to fully qualify your path as in "c:\filepath.txt" because be default it will write the text file in the default path location for the process that is running the command.